# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre llamar a una función con su parámetro y cuando se la explicita de forma anónima con el mismo parámetro?

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, parámetros

Realicé un ejercicio donde debí mostrar las coordenadas del mouse en pantalla.

La cuestión es que a la hora de llamar a la función que realiza dicho trabajo, no funciona si la llamo como se haría normalmente

```
body.onmousemove = mostrarPosMouse(event);
```

Luego encontré esta solución que hace el trabajo esperado

```
body.onmousemove = function (event) {
    mostrarPosMouse(event);
};
```

**Mi pregunta es:** Que tiene la función anónima que hace posible el correcto funcionamiento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La diferencia es que en el primer fragmento de código no se está atando una función sino más bien la ejecución de una función (eventualmente, el valor que dicha función retorne).
En este caso debería ser:

```
// Definición de la función
function mostrarPosMouse(event) {
    // ...
};

// Atar la función al evento, no la ejecución. Nótese la ausencia de ()
// ya que no queremos ejecutarla, sólo atarla al evento
body.onmousemove = mostrarPosMouse;
```

Comment: Perfecto, se entendio.
Solo una duda, en body.onmousemove = mostrarPosMouse, no es necesario que le digamos el parametro que recibe?

Comment: No es necesario ya que sólo estamos referenciando la función. Al momento de ejecutarla, JS se entiende con la definición y, el que la ejecute, pasará el parámetro definido. Los eventos de JS por defecto proveen el "event" con la info. de cómo se ha emitido, quién lo emitió, etc.

Answer (score 3):

#### Que tiene la función anónima que hace posible el correcto funcionamiento?

Una cosa muy sencilla: una función anónima es, **en si misma**, una expresión.

Clarificamos un poco:

```
variable = expresión
```

Esa sentencia **asigna** a la variable `variable` el resultado de **evaluar** la `expresión`.

Eso hace posible, por ejemplo, que esto funcione:

```
var x = ( 5 * 2 + 10 );
```

El motor de Javascript primero **evalúa lo situado a la derecha** del operador `=`, y es el resultado de esa evaluación lo que se *asinga* a `variable`.

Ahora, veamos el resultado de evaluar **una función**:

```
function algo( ) { }
var variable = algo( );
```

Fíjemos en **los paréntesis** `(` y `)`. **Eso** es la *marca distintiva* de una *llamada  a función*. Al encontrarse con `nombre_de_variable (` , el lenguaje entiende que eso es una **expresión**, cuyo resultado final es el valor retornado por la llamada a la función `nombre_de_variable`.

Por lo tanto, en tu ejemplo:

```
body.onmousemove = mostrarPosMouse(event);
```

1. Se evalua `event` (si no es una variable local, se usa `window.event` en el navegador).
2. Se llama a la función `mostrarPosMouse( )` con un argumento: el resultado del punto `1`.
3. A `body.onmousemove` se le asigna el valor retornado en el punto `2`.

Si como *expresión* usas una funcionan anónima, las cosas transcurren de manera similar ... pero **no** idéntica:

```
body.onmousemove = function (event) {
  mostrarPosMouse(event);
};
```

1. El motor encuentra la palabra clave `function`, y entiende que eso es una declaración de función.
2. La declaración de función **devuelve** una referencia a la función recién creada.
3. La referencia obtenida en `2` **es usada** como valor a asignar.

Podríamos decir que

```
function (event) {
  mostrarPosMouse(event);
};
```

es, en cierto modo, igual que si hicieramos

```
{
  return ( function( event ) { mostrarPosMouse( event ); ); }
}
```

La Mozilla Developer Network, como *casi* siempre, tiene una excelente documentación sobre [las funciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Funciones), con un apartado sobre las [*expresiones de función*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Funciones#Expresiones_de_funci%C3%B3n).

Comment: Genial la informacion que me acabas de dar. Te lo agradezco mucho. Solo me surgio una duda con respecto a cuando se llama a una funcion usando los parentesis, y es la de que al final devuelve un resultado, pero una sola vez (A body.onmousemove se le asigna el valor retornado en el punto 2.)? Lo que impide el movimiento de la figura con el mouse?

Comment: Si `mostrarPosMouse( event );` devuelve, por ejemplo, el número `5`, es **ese número** el que se asigna a `body.onmousemove`; por supuesto, como `body.onmousemove` espera **una función**, pues ignora ese valor (ese `5`) y no hace nada.